# Is this the proper way to use the bool 'or' operator?

Tags: c++, boolean

```cpp
userString[count] == '!' || '.' || '?'
```

I am trying to say if the left equals ! or .(period) or ?

Comment: no, you need to do `userString[count] == '!' || userString[count] == '.' || userString[count] == '?'`

Comment: That is what I thought at first but was shying away from it because my coding class frowns upon using repetitive code, in this case userString[count] three times. I wonder if theres a library function that returns true for punctuation. thank you!

Comment: There's `ispunct()` from `<cctype>`, but that returns true for more punctuation characters than the three you show (such as `,` and `(` and `>`, etc).  Otherwise, you could look at a search algorithm that takes a string with the acceptable characters and looks up the current character in the string — in C, you could use `strchr(".!?", userString[count])` (from `<string.h>` — presumably `<cstring>` in C++), or something similar.

Comment: Well, one can always fallback to C and try `if (strchr("!,?", userString[count]) != 0)`. Nothing wrong with using C. But only if it's used correctly, of course.

Comment: or `if (std::string{"!.?"}.find(userString[count]) != std::string::npos)` or c++17 forwards:  `if (std::string_view{"!.?"}.find(userString[count]) != std::string_view::npos)`